# heroku adddon rails how to call endpoint of authentificatation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, heroku

1. When a heroku creates resources:
   a) Make a call to the endpoint of authentication:

   ```
   POST https://app.starving.cloud.io/v1/profile/users/email/{email}/sign-in
   ```

   with the body

   ```
   (Content-Type: application / json)
    {
     "password": "{password}"
    }
   ```

   The endpoint returns the token as json:

   ```
   {
    "token": "{token}"
   }
   ```

Please help me. how to create this is? Or what i should to read about it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Tell us more about this, it seems that it is documentation for an API, not Heroku's, what part are you having trouble with?  What part of this is related to Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Comment: i dont understand how i should include  this is POST https://app.starving.cloud.io/v1/profile/users/email/{email}/sign-in  and how to call  endpoint of authentication.... sorry if i tell a lot of info :( May be you can show me example on gist or something else...

Comment: Nope, we have the opposite problem. You aren't giving us much information to work with, but I'll do my best: see answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an API you need to consume (hit, etc), you can use an HTTP Client library like [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) to write code that does the POST request and allows you to read the token from the response's body:

```
email = 'foo@example.com'
password = 'password' # Never use this password!
response = Typhoeus.post("https://app.starving.cloud.io/v1/profile/users/email/#{email}/sign-in",
                         headers: { 'Content-Type'=> 'application/json' },
                         body: { password: password }.to_json)
token = JSON.parse(response.body)['token']
```

Please read the gem's documentation to build the best version of this code, but this should give you an idea and a starting point.